# ADO.NET Entity Data Model of MySQL in VS 2015 Community Update 1

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

In ADO.NET Entity Data Model I can connect to MySQl, but when I click Next, nothing happens and I cannot choose tables (db first approach).

[image]

Comment: +1 same problem here. FW4.5, MySql.Data/Entity 6.10.6, EF 6.2.0. Perhaps the negative votes are for not specifying the versions you used.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify an option for the "Yes/No" question to sensitive data being stored in connection string before the Next button is enabled.

Comment: Unsuccessful screen. Next button is enabled! I click Next and ... nothing

Comment: I'd imagine it could be something to do with the installation of MySQL. Might be worth trying an reinstall. Apologies for no clear direction on this. Hope to have a bit more info for you as I'm testing it here myself.

Comment: I testing on another PC and its works fine! Mb i repair install my VS ?